# How to add units on a scale using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm currently using ggplot to create a chart.

I would like to know how to add units on my scale (like a suffix).

This is the codes lines for the scale :

```
mean <- mean(DTA[, 2]) # column two mean from my data frame

scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(mean -10, mean - 5, mean, mean + 5, mean + 10))
```

So if `mean` = 100, the scale is : 90 95 100 105 110

How to add "%" ? (to obtain this : 90% 95% 100% 105% 110%)

I tried this code but it doesn't works :

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks = bquote(c(mean -10, mean - 5, mean, mean + 5, mean + 10)~. (%)))
```

Thank you

Comment: use the scales package and check out `percent_format` and `number_format(suffix='%')` ( I think thats the code)

Comment: You want to specify `labels` not `breaks`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comments stated there are several ways of doing so. In any case what you want is to use the `labels` argument in the `scale_*_continuous` (or `scale_*_discrete`) to specify formatting. The simplest way is to use the `scales` package, which provides some easy-to-use formatting functions, such as `percent` and `percent_format`.

In `ggplot2` you can specify formats in 2 ways. Manual labels eg. `labels = c("30 %", "40 %", ...)` and as a function `labels = percent`. Below I've illustrated how this can be done using the `mtcars` dataset

```
data("mtcars")
mtcars$RatioOfOptimalMpg <- with(mtcars, mpg / max(mpg)) 
scales::percent(mtcars$RatioOfOptimalMpg)[1:6]
#[1] "61.9%" "61.9%" "67.3%" "63.1%" "55.2%" "53.4%"
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = RatioOfOptimalMpg)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    labs(y = "% of best mpg observed") + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image: Image of mtcars ggplot with percentage scales]

Now you might want to customize this formatting. In this case you can use `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(...))` replacing `...` with the formatting arguments. The `scales` package provides quite a few nifty functions for formatting discrete and continuous variables, and you'll find it mentioned here and there on SO.

Using this idea a simple method for creating any wished format is thus either explicitly writing out the labels

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = RatioOfOptimalMpg * 100)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    labs(y = "% of best mpg observed") + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = paste0(RatioOfOptimalMpg * 100, " %"))
```

or similarly creating a function like `scales::percent` which would do the formatting for you

```
addPercent <- function(x, ...) #<== function will add " %" to any number, and allows for any additional formatting through "format".
    format(paste0(x, " %"), ...)
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = RatioOfOptimalMpg * 100)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    labs(y = "% of best mpg observed") + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = addPercent)
```

Note in both cases I've multiplied my `RatioOfOptimalMpg` by 100, as my values are in decimal percentage.

Comment: My chart must be reusable with other datas (%, grams, hundredweight) and I just want to change the unit like this. (I understand that your code convert the datas in percent, is it true ?). In my case, I just want to add "%" after my breaks.

Comment: Example added in about 50 seconds.

Comment: You are correct in your assesment. `scales::percent` basically multiplies by `100` and adds ` %` to the output. Instead you can use `paste(..., sep = "")` or `paste0(...)` merge the numbers and the percentage sign.

Comment: It works well for me with `past0` : `unit <- function(x) {format(paste0(x, " %"))}` It's perfect. Thank you!